# get maven to call a method before jar

Tags: maven

how do i get maven to run a specific method of mine before it creates the jar file?

basically, i have java code in my junits folder (not a test, just a class with a

```
 main([path to save to])
```

) that generates an xml file that must be included in the jar.  how do i get maven to follow this flow?

compile

run custom method to create xml file passing it the path of the build folder (this method needs the full classpath of the project to run)

jar classes

Answer (score 1):

Bind the maven exec plugin to the `generate-resources` phase. And your are done.

Comment: The Java code which should be executed won't be compiled at this time as the generate-resources phase runs before the compile phase.

Answer (score 0):

In short, make it a plugin/MOJO.

In long, philosophy of Maven is not having you to write the build logic inside.  It is a more declarative approach.

Anyway, you still have a last resort: use maven-antrun plugin to write a short logic to call whatever u need as ant target.